# how to hook UIView's animation?

Tags: iphone

I want to send my own message during UIView's animation process. 
For example:

```
myView.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{myView.alpha = 0.0;} completion:^(BOOL isFinished){}];
```

I want to send the message when iOS render the specific alpha's animation frame.

```
- (void) alphaChangedTo:(float) val
{
    [sendMyOwnMessage:val];
}
```

as the animation is carried out by the iOS system, can I hook the function to finish my task? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried animation code block??

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];

[sendMyOwnMessage:val];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for.. but I hope this helps.. Cheers!! Happy Coding.

Comment: thanks, But I want to sendMyWonMessage each frame, I think the code above you posted will sendMyOwnMessage only once.